# I can't see the complete menu of applications installed

Tags: 20.04, appmenu

[image: app menu]I extended the life of my old netbook by changing from the HDD to a SSD, so I r haveeturned to ubuntu (20.04) since a long time.
The problem I have is that I can't see the whole list of appications installed.The system shows me the first page and don't let me go further. Appart from the fact I've previously described, the button "Fequent" and "All" at the bottom of the page are shaking subtly.
I hope someone could help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just for my understanding. Scrolling or moving around with arrow keys does not work?

Comment: Also provide information on your graphics and hardware: the "shaking" may be an issue with the graphics card. PageDown or clicking on the second white dot should normally move you to the next page.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Not even using a mouse.

Device-1: Intel Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics 
  vendor: Samsung Co Notebook N150P driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: i915 resolution: 1024x600~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Pineview M v: 1.4 Mesa 20.2.6 
  direct render: Yes

As I have said; It's an old notebook